# how to reset Linux-Next to a specified date?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I have git cloned Linux-Next to my Linux box (Ubuntu1410). Now I would like to reset the linux-next to a one month ago state, and then build the kernel.
How do I revert my linux-next source tree to a that specific date?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should find the commit which you want to reset.
And, do the blow command:
               git reset --hard

Comment: Thanks! One more question:how do I find a commit 3 months ago?